# jQuery parse xml and keep order

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml with mixed node content, I want to parse the xml and extract information based on the order that they appear in.

For example :

```
<booklist>
  <hardcover>
   <title>some title </title>
  </hardcover>
  <paperback>
   <title>some title </title>
  </paperback>
  <paperback>
   <title>some title </title>
  </paperback>
  <hardcover>
   <title>some title </title>
  </hardcover>
  <paperback>
   <title>some title </title>
  </paperback>
  <paperback>
   <title>some title </title>
  </paperback>
  <hardcover>
   <title>some title </title>
  </hardcover>
</booklist>
```

---

I initially extracted each type using $.find() then concatenated the list back together, but the order is lost.

```
   jQuery(xml).find('hardcover').each(function(){
...
     hardcoverlist.push(hardcoverobj);

..});


   jQuery(xml).find('paperback').each(function(){
    paperbacklist.push(paperbackobj);
..});
```

Is there a way to tell find() to look for either/or   ? 
like so **jQuery(xml).find('paperback || hardcover')**

Comment: `jQuery(xml).find('hardcover,paperback').each(function (){ ... });`

Comment: @Phylogenesis excellent  can you place that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery has support for [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
jQuery(xml).find('hardcover, paperback').each(function() {
    // ...
});
```